# Out of BoundsException

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have to create a program that will find commonDates within a list of People.

```
public DateSet commonDates() {
        if (persons.size() >= 2) {
            DateSet Cdates = 
persons.get(0).getDateSet().intersection(persons.get(1).getDateSet());
            for (int i = 2; i < persons.size(); i++) {
                Cdates = Cdates.intersection(persons.get(i).getDateSet());
            }
            return Cdates;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
       }
    }
```

this is the intersection method:

```
public DateSet intersection(DateSet other) {
    DateSet dates2 = (DateSet) other;
    DateSet NewDateSet = new DateSet();
    for(int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
        if (dates.get(i).equals(dates2.dates.get(i))) {
            NewDateSet.add(dates.get(i));
        }
    }
    return NewDateSet;
}
```

The Junit test for commonDates looks like this

```
@Test
public void testCommonDates() {
    DatePicker persons = new DatePicker();
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Person P1 = new Person("Joop");
    Person P2 = new Person("Joopie");
    Person P3 = new Person("Jaapie");
    Date D1 = new Date("maandag");
    Date D2 = new Date("dinsdag");
    dates.add(D1);
    persons.addPerson(P1);
    persons.addPerson(P2);
    P1.add(D1);
    P2.add(D1);
    P3.add(D1);
    P1.add(D2); 
    assertThat("commonDates should return dates all persons have in common", persons.commonDates(), equalTo(dates));
}
```

These are the error messages that I get
[image: These are the error messages that i get]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would really help if you'd reduce this to a [mcve] - and follow Java naming conventions as you go. While we do have everything we need to reproduce this, there's more than required, and it's not in a convenient form to reproduce. Additionally, you haven't told us what your diagnostic investigations have shown. (Hint: I'm pretty sure the problem is that your `intersection` method assumes that both `DateSet`s have the same number of entries...)

Comment: Most of the datatypes you mention in the code are not part of Java Standard, what are those?

Comment: Can you try size()-1 for every for loop?

Comment: I don't see why you start from the third element ```for (int i = 2; i < persons.size(); i++) {...}``` something's not right there. And note hat ```size()``` is n+1 where n is the last index of an array starting from 0.

Answer (score 1):

Check the loop

```
for (int i = 2; i < persons.size(); i++) {
                Cdates = Cdates.intersection(persons.get(i).getDateSet());
}
```

Your `for`-loop variable `i` starts with initial value 2 and it is incrementing, whereas it should be decrementing, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a separate test for the `public DateSet intersection(DateSet other)` method, since there is where your issue is. It looks like there is a issue since it expects the same length of the sets.

You should probably use something like

```
Set<Date> intersection = new HashSet<>(dates1);
intersection.retainAll(dates2);
```

instead of using custom data types.